# WinRT Runtime Customization Background Colors

Tags: xaml, colors, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime

I'm trying to figure out how to use custom background colors for the entire application in WinRT.  Essentially, I want to give the user an option to change the background color code.  Selection and storage of this is easy.  What I'm failing to see is how to set it so that it:

A) changes immediately when the user changes the color.
B) use resource dictionaries to set the background color

Originally, I just set the background color for each frame/page by setting the background color of each base grid to the color I had statically set.  I tried using binding to bind the color, but that doesn't seem to work.

So, I tried breaking the background color out into a Resource Dictionary to see if I could get one setting to apply to the app, but even that doesn't seem to work (doesn't compile).  Like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Page.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Black"/>
    </Page.Background>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I also tried applying it to frame rather than page, but that doesn't seem to compile either.  And I can't seem to get anything to compile to just set one common App color, first of all.

The second is once that is working, how to change the ResourceDictionary on the fly to apply new background colors.

I've searched the internet and multiple sites trying to find examples, but don't any good examples of this even being done.

An answer to the first and hopefully easiest question would be fantastic.  Help on setting the background would be icing on the cake!

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a bit difficult to do in WinRT/XAML since it doesn't have the `{DynamicResource}` concept of WPF, so even if you programmatically modify the resource dictionaries (which should be doable) - you'll still need to somehow trigger the entire UI tree to reload. Perhaps by going navigating back and forth in your root frame (assuming you use one)?